# Which WYSIWYM editor to use?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, wmd, wysiwym

I need a WYSIWYM markdown editor for my web application and I heard WMD was the obvious choice.

To my surprise WMD breaks in IE8.  What other option do I have, or is there a version that's been tested on IE8 and is compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [wmd-new](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/). According to its website:

> This version of WMD has been tested with IE 6, 7 and 8 RC1, Firefox 3, Safari 3.2, Chrome 1.0 and Opera 9.6. iPhone and iPod Touch support is rumored to work with the exception of the link/image prompt location. There are a few (minor) known issues with keyboard handling in IE and Opera. See the issues page for more details.
>
> [...]
>
> **NOTE**
>
> Version 2.0 of this code was developed as a private bugfix/feature branch for Stackoverflow.com and is missing most of the optional features found in the original WMD as SO did not use them. Now that I'm putting this out on Google Code I'll be adding the new features back in v2.1 due out sometime in February 2009. Version 3.0 should be released in February/March 2009 and will a major rewrite making use of jQuery.

**EDIT:** I didn't notice it immediately but this project hasn't release any source code.

**EDIT2:** As pointed out by warren in a comment, a "Stack Overflow branch of WMD" is hosted on [github](http://github.com/derobins/wmd). See [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) for more details.

Comment: I tried it. I know SO uses and improved version of this. But I could not find source code anywhere on their site.

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/ - http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master

Comment: Even this here you can not download.

Comment: @Ankit Can you elaborate? Are you familiar with git?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org) myself, but their [supported browsers](http://www.wymeditor.org/features/) are:

- Gecko-based browsers (Firefox 2.0+, SeaMonkey, Galeon, Epiphany, ...)
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
- Opera 9.5+
- Safari 3.1+
- Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

The version of WMD on [derobins' github](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) should work fine with IE8.

Comment: Try http://github.com/derobins/wmd/zipball/master

Recommended way is to use `git clone git://github.com/derobins/wmd.git` though.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest [Tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) a wonderful Javascript **WYSIWYG** Editor, with loads of functionalities, and its opensource, it as versions for PHP, ASP, JSP and CouldFusion, multi language, and some others functions, very simple to customize with only the specific functions you want him to enable for your users.

Check out Tinymce website:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com

Regards

**EDIT:**

I been using it for the past two years never had any problems with it.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is asking for a WYSIWYM editor, not a WYSIWYG...

Comment: Yes I've noticed that, thats why i mentioned WYSIWYG in capitalized letters, but with the level of customization that Tinymce is enabled to, he can take its functionalities close to the ones of WMD.

Comment: WYSIWYG is an acronym and acronyms are **always** in capital letters so I didn't notice the emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

There is one listed on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) page - but I've not used it: [WYMeditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYMeditor)